# git repo with two users getting permission errors

Tags: git

I have a deployment repo on my web server that I want multiple users to be able to push to.
The problem is that the files are owned by whoever originally setup the repo.

When user2 deploys they get this message:

```
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects
```

I tried to fix it by doing this:

```
chgrp -R GROUP /path/to/repo
find /path/to/repo -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;
```

But I still get permission errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to set the permissions to allow writing too? I think chmod g+w should do it for all files and directories.